# SwiftSpinner in initial load is not working

Tags: ios, swift

Upon calling SwiftSpinner, on `viewDidLoad` , Swift spinner is not working

Please find below the code i am using,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                self.basicSync {(isSynced) in
                     DispatchQueue.main.async {
                         SwiftSpinner.hide()
                     }
                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                SwiftSpinner.show("Syncing")
            }
}

public func basicSync(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
        //Sync related work
        completion("true")
}
```

I am not able to find a way to call Swift spinner on initial load

Some of the methods i tried with SwiftSpinner.Show from above code

1. To call,
   `SwiftSpinner.show("Syncing")`
2. To call it main inside main thread

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
                SwiftSpinner.show("Syncing")
            }
          }
```

3. I was able to achieve it when it is written like this,

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        SwiftSpinner.show("Syncing")
                    }
                }
            }
```

But I dont think it is the correct coding standard, new to Swift and coding technology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this issue before, you need to do the following

```
func delay(seconds: Double, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let popTime = DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64( Double(NSEC_PER_SEC) * seconds )) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: popTime) {
        completion()
    }
}
```

then in view did load

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    delay(seconds: 0.5) {
       SwiftSpinner.show("Syncing")
    }
}
```

That's it :D

Comment: Thank you its working perfectly, if i understand correctly calling main right after the sync was the problem and you have added delay time to call the Spinner in main thread, am i correct? I am new to coding environment and trying to understand the code. Why is it necessary to call with a delay?

Comment: hmm from my experience and this problem with all HUD looks like they all have the same issue not only this anything have animation layout constraint view change anything even the gradient won't works if you put it inside the viewdidload , so that make delay so the screen can load everything UI Size etc .. then  it works , something else it's something strange for now :/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it in

> viewdidappear